# 2 inner joins 2 tables mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 3 tables.

```
users
------------
id   |  Name   |
------------
44   |   user1 |
45   |useradmin|

Sections
------------
id | Name
------------
1  | Test   |

Assigns
------------
id | u_id | section_id | admin_u_id
-----------------------------------
1  | 44   |    1       |    45     |
```

I am trying to pull up the `Assigns` table and replace u_id and admin_u_id with the respective users names and section_id with the sections name.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT Assigns.u_id, Assigns.id, users.id,users.id
FROM Assigns
INNER JOIN users
ON Assigns.u_id=users.id
INNER JOIN users
ON Assigns.admin_u_id=users.id
INNER JOIN Sections
ON Assigns.section_id=Sections.id
```

What throws me off is the Select line. I want it to display users.id twice with different values.

Any help or push in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!

EDIT:
Here are the actual table names.

I do not get any errors in my MYSQL query just an empty set is returned

```
SELECT mrfv0_codes_assign.u_id, mrfv0_codes_assign.id, u1.id,u2.id 
FROM mrfv0_codes_assign 
INNER JOIN mrfv0_users u1 ON mrfv0_codes_assign.u_id=u1.id 
INNER JOIN mrfv0_users u2 ON mrfv0_codes_assign.admin_u_id=u2.id 
INNER JOIN mrfv0_codes_sections ON mrfv0_codes_assign.section_id=mrfv0_codes_sections.id
```

**EDIT2:
I am an idiot. I didn't set up my table properly. You all had the right answer!
Sorry for wasting your time!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.u_id,
       a.id,
       u1.name AS Username,
       u2.name AS AdminUsername,
       s.name AS SectionName
FROM mrfv0_codes_assign a
INNER JOIN mrfv0_users u1 ON a.u_id = u1.id
INNER JOIN mrfv0_users u2 ON a.admin_u_id = u2.id
INNER JOIN mrfv0_codes_sections s ON a.section_id = s.id
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c517/1)

**Output**

```
| U_ID | ID | USERNAME | ADMINUSERNAME | SECTIONNAME |
------------------------------------------------------
|   44 |  1 |    user1 |     useradmin |        Test |
```

Comment: I was also returned an empty set. This I put up everything that is in the Tables. If you could have another look its greatly appreciated.

Comment: Updated with SQL Fiddle Example.

Comment: @MatA section ID 1 does not exist in your example. You can avoid issues like this by taking advantage of referential integrity features of your db (e.g., foreign keys).

Comment: do you have anywhere I can read up on proper use of foreign keys? for MySQL

Thanks!

Comment: @MatA Start with the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Assigns.id AS id,
       users.name AS user_name, 
       admins.name AS admin_name, 
       Sections.name AS section_name
FROM Assigns
INNER JOIN users ON Assigns.u_id = users.id
INNER JOIN users AS admins ON Assigns.admin_u_id = admins.id
INNER JOIN Sections ON Assigns.section_id=Sections.id
```

Just add an alias on your INNER JOIN, it allows you to distinct user "user" table from user "admin" table.

Here, your result will be this kind of array : `[id, user_name, admin_name, section_name]`

Comment: When using your query I was returned an empty set. No errors.

Comment: SELECT mrfv0_codes_assign.id AS id,
       mrfv0_users.name AS user_name, 
       admins.name AS admin_name, 
       mrfv0_codes_sections.name AS section_name
FROM mrfv0_codes_assign
INNER JOIN mrfv0_users ON mrfv0_codes_assign.u_id = mrfv0_users.id
INNER JOIN mrfv0_users AS admins ON mrfv0_codes_assign.admin_u_id = admins.id
INNER JOIN mrfv0_codes_sections ON mrfv0_codes_assign.section_id=mrfv0_codes_sections.id

Comment: if you could look again its greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to put aliases on each table (it will be clearer) : `SELECT assigns.id AS id, users.name AS user_name, admins.name AS admin_name, sections.name AS section_name FROM mrfv0_codes_assign AS assigns INNER JOIN mrfv0_users AS users ON assigns.u_id = users.id INNER JOIN mrfv0_users AS admins ON assigns.admin_u_id = admins.id INNER JOIN mrfv0_codes_sections AS sections ON assigns.section_id = sections.id`

Comment: Still returning an empty set... I am lost. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I just created a database with your datas, and it works. Check your table/column names, and see if you've got any error (in your PHP file : `error_reporting(E_ALL);`)

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning aliases to your tables. Example:

```
SELECT Assigns.u_id, Assigns.id, u1.id,u2.id
FROM Assigns
INNER JOIN users u1
ON Assigns.u_id=u1.id
INNER JOIN users u2
ON Assigns.admin_u_id=u2.id
INNER JOIN Sections
ON Assigns.section_id=Sections.id
```

Comment: I was returned an empty set from this query even though I know the id's match.

Comment: if you could look again with the updated data its greatly appreciated